# How do i call a void function from the codebehind?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

When calling a codebehind function from a aspx file I use this tag:

```
<%# FunctionName(param) %>
```

But when using this tag the function is always requires to return a string. How do i call a void function from the codebehinde in an `aspx` file?

Comment: When do you want this method to be called?

Comment: Why you need this? I believe you are looking for a way to call a function on a specific stage of a page loading?

Comment: I don't understand why you would need to call a void method during databinding... c

Answer (score 7):

`<%#` is used to write (sanatized) output to the response, so it expects to have something to write (ie. a return value).  Try using `<% %>` instead.